# gRPC the protoc compiler creates not the expected

Tags: java, grpc, protoc

i start whith gRPC bulding an easy Java Chat Programm.

protc --version prints libprotoc 3.5.1

the -proto File:

```
syntax = "proto3";
option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "grpc";
// whihout this Option i get no service
option java_generic_services = true;
option java_outer_classname = "ChatProto";
option objc_class_prefix = "HLW";
package chat;
message ClientPost {
  string name = 1;
  string value = 2;
}
message ServerReply {
  ClientPost back = 1;
}
// The  service definition.
service  Verbindung {
  rpc ChatService (stream ClientPost) returns (stream ServerReply);
}
```

// file end

1. why i need to set the option java_generic_services ?

   class ChatImpl extends grpc.Verbindung {
       @Override
       public void chatService(RpcController controller, ClientPost request, RpcCallback done) {
         // why i get this kind of Service ?
       }
   }

//
2. why i get an other class name ? shut be VerbindungImplBase

expected Function

```
public void sayHello(HelloRequest req, StreamObserver<HelloReply> responseObserver) { }
```

3. what must i do to get this kind of expected Service Function ?

may be an wrong protoc compiler / wrong Installation / missing Parts ?

Answer (score 0):

You're likely not running the gRPC code generator. Without the full configuration of how you're running protoc I can't point out too much detail, but you are likely only generating the protobuf messages via java_generic_services=true.

You shouldn't need java_generic_services=true. Instead, you should generate the messages like you are now, but then also use the grpc-java plugin. There's documentation for [when running protoc manually](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/compiler/README.md) and our main documentation [documents the preferred method](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/README.md), using Maven or Gradle plugins.

Comment: Ok i see; the protoc Compiler needs an plugin. at this point i have not found an compiled Version of this Plugin (runnung open Suse leap 42.2)

Comment: Pre-built binaries for grpc-java's plugin are available on Maven Central: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22io.grpc%22%20a%3A%22protoc-gen-grpc-java%22

Comment: the pre-build cange nothing :-(  i got the same output

Comment: the pre-buld plugin change nothing - i get the same output try to compile the plugin ,fail :java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: net/ltgt/gradle/errorprone/ErrorPronePlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Answer (score 0):

I have an open suse leap 42.2 System
this Version knows nothing about grpc - no Support from this side

i get the compiled protoc - it comes whithout the needed Java-gen Plugin

found https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/compiler/README.md

"Normally you don't need to compile the codegen by yourself, since pre-compiled binaries for common platforms are available on Maven Central."

i found only some exe files. - not useful

"Change to the compiler directory:"

i have no compiler dir. - still try to find out were i can get

NetBeans have only an Editor plugin for protofiles - so my IDE can't handel gRPC

maybe for other IDEs are the Maven Plugins for gRPC are helpful

i expected an full protoc Compiler with all needed plugins :-)
not an install  the tool adventure.

a the Moment for me: gRPC - nice Idea , but i get an "install the gRPC" Adventure